# Call a function on Button OnClick

Tags: c#, asp.net

is there a way to call a function in asp.net using c# from code behind when a button is clicked.

Example in code behind i have a button,

```
Button btnRemove = new Button();
```

btnremove.OnClientclick = Remove(ID) something like that??

I want to call a function

```
public void Remove(int ID)
{

}
```

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: You wish to call a method on click of a button? Why not attach it to a server side event? OnClick event?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Client Side

If you use `OnClientClick` you call Javascript method

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.onclientclick.aspx

Server Side

A If you want call server method you can use `OnClick`

```
Button1.Click += new EventHandler(this.Button1_Click);

void Button1_Click (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var control = (Button)sender;
    Remove(control.Id);
}
```

B you can also override your Click delegate

```
protected override void OnClick(EventArgs e)
{
    Remove(this.Id);
}
```

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.onclick.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Hmm...you first need to distinguish between client-side execution (JavaScript) and server-side execution (ASP.net).

For client-side execution, you need to write your "function" in JavaScript and (as you already wrote correctly) use the `OnClientClick` property to register that function.

For server-side execution you either need to

- post the form back to the server s.t. a server-side click event handler gets fired
- use ajax to asynchronously call the server (i.e. a web method on your ASPX Page or an ASMX service). Again, this involves JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

I had to register my buttonId (aspx) as a postbacktrigger(aspx.cs)

```
RegisterPostbackTrigger(lnkExcel1)
```